# multiple floats with clear, yet right ones are pushed down by left ones

Tags: css, css-float

so I have this code:

html:

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

css:

```
.left{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/839okvsb/4/

Left divs are where I would expect them to be, but right ones start after div 2 instead starting on top.

**Why is that, and how can I fix that?** I absolutely cannot grasp why is this happening.

PS: I cannot contain left divs into one gigantic div, I need those divs separated (because sometimes, div1 will be full width and sometimes not).

**edit**: I cannot mix them up and as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/839okvsb/5/ / mixing still doesn't solve the issue.

**edit2**: I cannot pack them in one big div, because I need them to be able to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/839okvsb/8/ when I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't create a 2 "column" layout using float left/right like that (even if you clear them), you need to have your markup like this, or else you get the result showed in your question, as that is how floats work.

```css
.left{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 48%;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left 1</div>
<div class="right">right 1</div>
<div class="left">left 2</div>
<div class="right">right 2</div>
<div class="left">left 3</div>
<div class="right">right 3</div>
```

Or wrap your floats

```css
.left{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 48%;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 48%;
}
.left .left{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.right .right{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="left">left 1</div>
  <div class="left">left 2</div>
  <div class="left">left 3</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="right">right 1</div>
  <div class="right">right 2</div>
  <div class="right">right 3</div>
</div>
```

Update based on edit/comment

If the left's and right's doesn't always be left and right, for example when one of them is 100% wide, here is another option, where all is floated left

```css
.left, 
.right {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 48%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}
.left:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.right {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.right{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left 1</div>
<div class="right">right 1</div>
<div class="left">left 2</div>
<div class="right">right 2</div>
<div class="left">left 3</div>
<div class="right">right 3</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot do that, and I am not sure that it would work with different heights.

Comment: @Gonzi Updated with a 2:nd suggestion

Comment: Yeah, but that I cannot do (I sometimes need for say div 2 to expand to full width). To clarify: I need to solve it with css, not html changes.

Comment: @Gonzi Update your question with such scenario or else we can't answer it properly.

Comment: @Gonzi Should the left's and right's always be left and right, even when one of them is 100% wide?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. I might solve my current issue with something similar, but I will have to use more classes, choose when to apply which one and stuff like that, so I am still wondering why my first code doesn't do what I expect. **Why does "clear: left" move even "float: right" divs.** But yeah, while generic solution doesn't work, I currently don't need it as much, so I will solve it for the time being with selective floats and clears.

Comment: @Gonzi Updated my answer with an explanation + 3:rd sample. If you use `flexbox` you will get more control of element order using the flex property `order`.